# side by side pref android

Tags: android, image, preferences

I would like to have two preferences side by side in a preference activity. An example is this:

[image](http://i42.tinypic.com/2vbnfih.png)
got from the wallpaper: Nebulander

I tried:

imagepref2.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img_2" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this shows as:
[this](http://i40.tinypic.com/nn4aqh.png)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what's the issue on your layout? I think the result fits exactly what you've defined in your layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your `android:layout_weight="1"` is at 1.
Change to 0.5.
And change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: No matters if layout_weight is 1 or 0.5 in this case because the `LinearLayout` hasn't any `weightSum` property defined.

Comment: remove the gravity line and put layout_gravity="center" on the linear layout. (sorry I haven't my android with me but I try help you)

Comment: The trick is: **android:layout_width="0dp"** and you can leave the weights to **1**